# Random variables in integrals, how to analyze?

Tags: integration, reference-request, soft-question, random-variables

Say I have a bunch of IDD random variables $\mathbb X_n$ with some distribution strictly in $\mathbb R^+$ (realistically we could even limit it to be on a compact subset, say $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R^+$), furthermore let us say we from this build

$$\mathbb S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb X_k$$
and then build something like
$$p(\mathbb X_k) = \frac{1}{\mathbb X_{k+1}}\int_{\mathbb S_{k}}^{\mathbb S_{k+1}}f(\tau)d\tau$$

Something like a "random sampling" procedure, $\mathbb X_k$ could be interpreted as some kind of exposure.

But to the question... How could we analyze something like this? I guess we will need to take help at least from both probability and analysis? Also any references to work which deals with this would be welcome.

Comment: what is the meaning of $p(\mathbb X_k)$? It's unclear how the RHS is to be viewed as a function of $\mathbb X_k.$

Comment: It seems like you are asking about averages of functions over random intervals. It's unclear what 'analyze' means to you. Maybe you can suggest a specific question about this set up that you want to answer?

Comment: to analyze things like expected errors and variances in different senses. well i guess i will need to update more specifically. part of the problem is that since i don't know many references i don't know what errors, expected values or variances would be interesting, fruitful or useful.

Comment: Is $f(t)$ a given (deterministic) function of $t$?  You can simplify notation by assuming $\{X_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ are iid positive random variables, and defining new random variables $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n X_k$, $Z_{k+1} = \frac{1}{X_{k+1}} \int_{S_k}^{S_{k+1}} f(t)dt$.  You could potentially evaluate $E[Z_{k+1}]$ by $$E[Z_{k+1}] = E[E[Z_{k+1}|S_k]] $$ and noting that $X_{k+1}$ is independent of $S_k$.

Comment: yes, $f(t)$ is deterministic.